# AutoMapper SQL optimization for mapping projection generation(NonNullable To Nullable)

Tags: sql, optimization, automapper, projection

**Here is the unit test code that reflects the problem::**

```
 public class NonNullableToNullable : AutoMapperSpecBase
    {
        public class Customer
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

            public virtual CustomerCategory Category { get; set; }
        }


        public class CustomerCategory
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public int GradeId { get; set; }

            public virtual CustomerGrade Grade { get; set; }
        }


        public class CustomerGrade
        {
            [Key]
            [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class CustomerViewModel
        {

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

            public string CategoryName { get; set; }

            public int? GradeId { get; set; }

            public string GradeName { get; set; }
        }

        public class Context : DbContext
        {
            public Context()
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DatabaseInitializer());
            }

            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

            public DbSet<CustomerCategory> CustomerCategories { get; set; }

            public DbSet<CustomerGrade> CustomerGrades { get; set; }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                    .HasOptional(a => a.Category).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.CategoryId);

                modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerCategory>().HasKey(a => a.Id)
                    .HasRequired(a => a.Grade).WithMany().HasForeignKey(a => a.GradeId);

                modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerGrade>().HasKey(a => a.Id);

                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            }
        }

        public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>
        {
            protected override void Seed(Context context)
            {
                context.CustomerGrades.Add(new CustomerGrade() { Id = 1, Name = "A" });

                context.CustomerCategories.Add(new CustomerCategory() { Id = 10, GradeId = 1, Name = "Category 1" });


                context.Customers.Add(new Customer
                {
                    Id = 100,
                    FirstName = "Bob",
                    LastName = "Smith",
                });

                context.Customers.Add(new Customer
                {
                    Id = 101,
                    FirstName = "Tom",
                    LastName = "Thomas",
                    CategoryId = 10
                });

                base.Seed(context);
            }
        }

        protected override MapperConfiguration Configuration => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
           
            cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.CategoryName, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.Category.Name))
                // If you forget to cast to nullable, the resulting SQL will look terrible
                //.ForMember(d => d.GradeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.Category.GradeId))
                .ForMember(d => d.GradeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => (int?)e.Category.GradeId))
                
                .ForMember(d => d.GradeName, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.Category.Grade.Name))

                ;

            
        });

        [Fact]
        public void Can_map_with_projection()
        {
            

            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                var query = ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>(context.Customers).Where(a => a.GradeId == 1);


                var model = query.First();

                model.Id.ShouldBe(101);

                model.FirstName.ShouldBe("Tom");
                model.LastName.ShouldBe("Thomas");
            }
        }
    }
```

**readable map  expression:**

```
    ObjectQuery<NonNullableToNullable.Customer>
    .MergeAs(MergeOption.AppendOnly)
    .Select(
        dtoCustomer => new NonNullableToNullable.CustomerViewModel
        {
            CategoryId = dtoCustomer.CategoryId,
            CategoryName = dtoCustomer.Category.Name,
            FirstName = dtoCustomer.FirstName,
            GradeId = (dtoCustomer.Category == null) ? null : (int?)dtoCustomer.Category.GradeId,
            GradeName = dtoCustomer.Category.Grade.Name,
            Id = dtoCustomer.Id,
            LastName = dtoCustomer.LastName
        })
    .Where(a => a.GradeId == ((int?)1))
```

**bad sql(cannot use an index):**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
--The generated SQL is a little redundant
    CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE [Extent2].[GradeId] END AS [C1], 
    [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    CASE WHEN (1 = 0) THEN cast(0 as bigint) ELSE [Extent1].[Id] END AS [C2], 
    [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
    FROM   [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CustomerCategories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CategoryId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CustomerGrades] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[GradeId] = [Extent3].[Id]
 --The WHERE condition cannot use an index
    WHERE 1 = (CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[Id] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE [Extent2].[GradeId] END)
```

**If cast to nullable at mapping time**

```
 .ForMember(d => d.GradeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => (int?)e.Category.GradeId))
```

**the resulting SQL will conform to expectations:**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId], 
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent2].[GradeId] AS [GradeId], 
    [Extent3].[Name] AS [Name1], 
    [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName]
    FROM   [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CustomerCategories] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CategoryId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[CustomerGrades] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[GradeId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    WHERE 1 = [Extent2].[GradeId]


    ObjectQuery<NonNullableToNullable.Customer>
    .MergeAs(MergeOption.AppendOnly)
    .Select(
        dtoCustomer => new NonNullableToNullable.CustomerViewModel
        {
            CategoryId = dtoCustomer.CategoryId,
            CategoryName = dtoCustomer.Category.Name,
            FirstName = dtoCustomer.FirstName,
            GradeId = (int?)dtoCustomer.Category.GradeId,
            GradeName = dtoCustomer.Category.Grade.Name,
            Id = dtoCustomer.Id,
            LastName = dtoCustomer.LastName
        })
    .Where(a => a.GradeId == ((int?)1))
```

**So my question is, why isn't automapper cast nullable by default when the target type is nullable, or is there any configuration that can do this without manual conversion?**

Answer (score -1):

`ProjectTo` must be the last call in the chain. EF works with entities, not DTOs. So apply any filtering and sorting on entities and, as the last step, project to DTOs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, some scenarios are true, but some scenarios are more convenient based on DTO filtering.

Comment: You're misusing `ProjectTo` and then complaining about the results. It's not about what you want, it's about what's possible. You can try expression mapping too, but in the end EF will do the same thing.